# Code contracts doesn't check null condition. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts

Why doesn't Contracts for .NET complain about this code ?

```
private static User GetUser()
{
    var sFirstName = Console.ReadLine();
    var sLastName = Console.ReadLine();
    if (sLastName == "NULL")
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return new User(sLastName, sFirstName);
    }
}
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
        var oUser = GetUser();
        DisplayUser(oUser);
        Console.ReadLine();
        return 0;
}
private static void DisplayUser(User user)
{
    Contract.Requires(user != null);
    Console.WriteLine(user.ToString());
}
```

GetUser can return null, but contract never says that I must check the return value before passing it to DisplayUser. Why?

---

**AutoAnswer:** There is a Warning Level in Code Contracts config. I should have put it from low to hi.

Comment: Probably because it isn't null. Try checking `if(sLastName.IsNullOrEmpty())` instead.

Comment: @0A0D - if you enter the string `NULL`, you *would* get a `null` return value.

Comment: @HansKesting: Ah, missed that.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.contract.aspx) page, the contracts will not be enforced if you do not have the proper plugin installed in Visual Studio. Have you installed that plugin?

> You must install a Visual Studio add-in to enforce contracts. The Code
>   Contracts Premium Edition add-in lets you specify static and run-time
>   checking of code contracts on the project Properties page. If you do
>   not enable run-time checking, contracts such as the Contract.Ensures
>   method will not throw exceptions during run time if a contract is
>   violated. The Visual Studio add-in does not ship with Visual Studio
>   2010 or the Windows SDK.

Comment: I did install it. I check the checkbox "Perform Static Contract Checking".

If I replace GetUser by

    private static User GetUser()
    {
        return null;
    }

Contracts will complain.